# Custom view clipped when moved

Tags: android, view, android-custom-view

I have a custom view that gets clipped to its original bounds after it's moved. On a 4.4.4 KitKat device, the view draws just fine outside its bound, but on a 4.1.2 device, it gets  clipped. I've tried using [android:clipChildren](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html#attr_android%3aclipChildren) with no success. Any ideas?

Code and layout below:

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
        mIsDown = true;
        return true;
    }

    if(mIsDown && event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE){

        PointF pointF = new PointF(event.getRawX(), event.getRawY());
        setX(pointF.x - getWidth() / 2);
        setY(pointF.y - getHeight() / 2);

        return true;
    }

    if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){
        mIsDown = false;
        return true;
    }

    return super.onTouchEvent(event);
}
```

Layout:

```
<FrameLayout
    android:clipChildren="false"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/control_panel">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/preview_holder"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    </FrameLayout>

    <com.example.CustomView
        android:id="@+id/target_view"
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:layout_height="120dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:background="@null"
         />
</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: try to invalidate the parent also when moving

Comment: @MoshErsan I just tried that, but the view still gets clipped. I did a ((ViewGroup)getParent()).invalidate() in onTouchEvent.

Comment: set `android:clipChildren="false"` to every parent to this child

Comment: @MoshErsan I tried that too; no luck.

Comment: can you put the whole code on github?